# Not an Intersect (IN) but sort of. Where Col a row x intersects with col b.Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a matrix table.  6 columns wide and 6 rows deep.The first column has the numbers 0, 5,4,3,2,1 in that order.  The first row in the table is 0,1,2,3,4,5
so like this:

```
Column names   RM0 RM1 RM2 RM3 RM4 RM5        
                0   1   2   3   4  5
                5
                4
                3
                2
                1
```

each of the rows has words in it ie, `MEDIUM`, `HIGH`, `CRITICAL` etc.
I have a form the user fills  out that requires them to give a rating from 1-5 in two categories. Their selections correspond to one of the words in the matrix.  SO..after all that...I need to be able to select from the table something like this:

```
SELECT FROM TBLX WHERE RM0=4 INTERSECTS WITH RM4
```

I have look at IN but everything I see so far still requires you to have another WHERE x=y part.   Could I dump the whole table into an array somehow get what Im after?  As you can see, Im clueless in this regard.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. What do the `+` mean in your table?

Comment: + are just spacers

Comment: Why not just use spaces? To post a formatted table like this, paste in the plain text, mark it, then use the `{}` tool to indent it as code.

Comment: point taken Ill do that next time

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE :b2
       WHEN 1 THEN t.rm1
       WHEN 2 THEN t.rm2
       WHEN 3 THEN t.rm3
       WHEN 4 THEN t.rm4
       WHEN 5 THEN t.rm5
       ELSE ''
       END   AS `the_word` 
  FROM TBLX t
 WHERE t.rm0 = :b1
```

---

I'm confused by the table design. And even more confused by the first row... if you want to get that incorporated in the query, that would be inordinately complex.

In terms of a normal relational design, we'd represent this as rows for each pair of values, with a single word on each row.

```
 mymatrix

 x_rating  y_rating  the_word
 --------  --------  --------
        1         1  LOW
        1         2  LOW
        1         3  MEDIUM
        1         4  MEDIUM
        1         5  MEDIUM
        2         1  LOW
        2         2  MEDIUM
        2         3  MEDIUM
      ...        
        5         5  HIGH
```

An example of a query to get "the word" would be something like this:

```
 SELECT mx.the_word
   FROM mymatrix mx
  WHERE mx.x_rating = :b1
    AND mx.y_rating = :b2
```

---

To use that same query pattern with the original table, we could get that original table converted to look like the mymatrix table, using the values from the RM1 through RM5 columns in the RM0=0 row as the y_rating value. The SQL to do that is rather cumbersome:

```
SELECT mx.the_word
  FROM (
         SELECT t1.rm0    AS x_rating
              , s1.rm1    AS y_rating
              , t1.rm1    AS the_word
           FROM mytable t1
           JOIN mytable s1
             ON s1.rm0 = 0
            AND t1.rm0 > 0
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.rm0    AS x_rating
              , s2.rm1    AS y_rating
              , t2.rm1    AS the_word
           FROM mytable t2
           JOIN mytable s2
             ON s2.rm0 = 0
            AND t2.rm0 > 0
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t3.rm0    AS x_rating
              , s3.rm1    AS y_rating
              , t3.rm1    AS the_word
           FROM mytable t3
           JOIN mytable s3
             ON s3.rm0 = 0
            AND t3.rm0 > 0
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t4.rm0    AS x_rating
              , s4.rm1    AS y_rating
              , t4.rm1    AS the_word
           FROM mytable t4
           JOIN mytable s4
             ON s4.rm0 = 0
            AND t4.rm0 > 0
          UNION ALL
         SELECT t5.rm0    AS x_rating
              , s5.rm1    AS y_rating
              , t5.rm1    AS the_word
           FROM mytable t5
           JOIN mytable s5
             ON s5.rm0 = 0
            AND t5.rm0 > 0
       ) mx
WHERE mx.x_rating = :b1
  AND mx.y_rating = :b2
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different route.  I still used the matrix table but instead of trying to access when I need to retrieve information I queried the table once, took all the information and put it into an array like this:

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblriskmatrix`";
    if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "query failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    }
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   $arrayOfMatrix = array();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $arrayOfMatrix[] = $row;
   }
```

I then put the array into a session variable like this:

```
    $_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix'] = $arrayOfMatrix;
```

I then created some functions to get the keys pressed and passed them to another function that did an ajax call, passing the variables of the key presses script that took those variables and passed them into my session variable and returned the desired result. Like this:

```
    session_start();
    $a = $_GET['var_a'];
    $b = $_GET['var_b'];

   $response = array('response' => $_SESSION['arrayOfMatrix'][$a]["RM$b"]);
  echo json_encode($response);
```

The response is then passed to a form element and displayed. So with the matrix table in the session variable as an array  I can easily extract the contents of what is in cell of row x within column y.  Not sure if its the most technically correct route but it works.